# non blocking socket write performance in c++

Tags: c++, linux, performance, sockets

I am trying to measure performance of networking code, and I get very varied results. So far I was not able to explain it, maybe others will be able to help or point in the right direction.

So I create a socket:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int one = 1;
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one)));
current = fcntl(socket, F_GETFL);
fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK | current);
```

My messages are always around 200 bytes.
Code that sends the message is:

```
uint64_t start (nanotimestamp());
unsigned char * buf;
... 
//build a message
//few calls to snprintf
//buffer is preallocated
...
write(socket, buf, size);
uint64_t end (nanotimestamp());

performance = end - start;

uint64_t nanotimestamp()
{
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
return now.tv_sec * 1e9 + now.tv_nsec;
}
```

The code is being run on 64bit redhat 6. Compiled with gcc 4.4
Timings vary a lot from 20 to 80 microsecond, in rare cases > 100 us.

So if the call to write is non blocking why do i see such a difference?

Comment: Network performance is always subject to network traffic condition. It will also depend on the position of the other server/client you are talking to, whether he is in the same subnet or different

Comment: but I am not measuring network performance here, I am using non blocking socket, call to write returns without actually sending anything, so the performance should solely be related to the machine I am running it on.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for this measurement - it has significantly lower overhead than getting `CLOCK_REALTIME`. For my performance measurement (we need nanosecond precision) I use RDTSC counter:

With GCC 4.4+ (not 100% sure on this one, 4.6.1 implements this for sure) on Intel system you could use:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
uint64_t clock_count = __rdtsc();
```

or if not:

```
extern "C" {
    __inline__ uint64_t rdtsc()
    {
        uint32_t lo, hi;
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "xorl %%eax,%%eax \n        cpuid"
            ::: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
        return (uint64_t)hi << 32 | lo;
    }
}
```

then dividing the delta of clock counts by your CPU frequency by number of CPU frequency hertz will give you a very precise measurement at a fraction of the cost of `clock_gettime()`

Edit:

And to answer the actual question now :)

In your code, you're actually measuring 2 things - building the message and sending it. You can either measure them separately or move data building outside of the block. Writing data is expensive when you're measuring microseconds.

I would think that the problem is in combination snprintf() and cache miss. Format functions have very poor performance and since you're rebuilding data every time, there's a probability that you're getting a cache miss *every once in a while*, which should answer the question about variability.

Answer (score 1):

Interruptions by other threads, hardware or software interrupts has already been mentioned.

There's another thing to consider though. Depending on various factors, your non-blocking write() call might take very different code paths. E.g. it might have to allocate additional buffers, which takes time, or it might not have to. Or it might decide that the data should be sent right away, and go "straight to the metal" (call into the driver to deliver the data to the network interface for transmission).

Allocating buffers takes time, delivering the data to the network interface even more so.

So write() might be really fast (buffering the data in an existing buffer), a little bit slower (allocating an additional buffer) or "really" slow (going straight to the metal).

Answer (score 0):

You can't measure just 1 write, as the process might be suspended while calling write (this might account for >100us). Also, doing a syscall might introduce some variance.

You need to call write more often and measure the time for all of those calls combined.

Answer (score 0):

1. it would have been preferable to surround write() call only in order to know how much time does it take to perform its "non-blocking" duty.
2. The thread running that code may be prempted at any moment by the kernel. Which will schedule another thread/process on the current core. It will re-schedule your process later. 20-80us could be the execution time of another process. (While I was more expecting 20-50 milliseconds, but it depends on your kernel and its configuration).

Comment: ok, so looks like most probably it is kernel giving execution to other processes (my process is single threaded). Giving higher execution priority with renice could improve latency?

Comment: Renice would help surely since the scheduler use the 'nice' priority to compute a thread's quanta. But there is even better, resetting the scheduler class. Look for the man page of "int sched_setscheduler(pid_t pid, int policy, const struct sched_param *p)" and change the class to SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR . Your process will be consider UN-premptable by the scheduler. TO BE used with great CAUTION! If your process goes in a while(true) loop and NEVER return to the kernel, then you single core device will be 'frozen'. Moreover calling sched_setscheduler() requires the root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to separate out the `write()` calls that fail with EAGAIN from those which actually transfer data.  That might account for a lot of the discrepancy.

Also I wonder if TCP_NODELAY is really helping you in this scenario.  It might be worth toggling that as well.

Comment: How removing TCP_NODELAY would help me, if I just send couple messages per minute? When I need to send a message I need it to go out straight away.